# return exception when run one stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this stored procedure

```
create PROCEDURE spgetoutpatientidbyinpatientid
@pinpatientid int
AS

BEGIN

select  Patient_ID 
    from tblPatientAdmissionDetails 
    where ID=@pinpatientid and Status=1
END
GO
```

if this condition is wrong i got null exception.I want to return at least null value or anything.how can i avoid this error. In my code I use

```
<pre lang="c#">string  ds = UserDataBase.ExecuteScalar(Command).ToString();</pre>
```

How can I change my sql query..? or how can I avoid this exception

Comment: if you return NULL, you would have to check for `DBNull.Value` in your c# code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your procedure like this might help you , `return -1` if there is no record for you condition..

```
create PROCEDURE spgetoutpatientidbyinpatientid
@pinpatientid int
AS

BEGIN

  if exists( select  Patient_ID from tblPatientAdmissionDetails 
       where ID=@pinpatientid and Status=1) 
  begin
      select  Patient_ID from tblPatientAdmissionDetails 
       where ID=@pinpatientid and Status=1)
  end
  else 
  begin
      select -1 
  end
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

```
declare @bogus_int int, @result int
set @bogus_int = -1000

select @result = Patient_ID 
from tblPatientAdmissionDetails 
where ID=@pinpatientid and Status=1

select coalesce( @result, @bogus_int )
```

Answer (score 0):

From C#

```
string ds = "";
object val = UserDataBase.ExecuteScalar(Command);
if(val != null)
   ds = val.ToString();
```

Comment: May be the null exception on `UserDataBase` object or the `Command` object

Answer (score 0):

Returning no rows is not really an error at the SP level; I would advise *against* changing the SP here. Really, then, it comes down to how you call it, and check for no-rows vs null vs data.

You *can* do this via the command, but it is a bit messy. My preference here would be to simplify; for example, to call with [dapper](http://nuget.org/packages/Dapper) with your existing stored procedure:

```
int id = 123;
var activePatient = connection.Query<int>(
    "spgetoutpatientidbyinpatientid", // command
    new { pinpatientid = id }, // parameters
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).Single();
```

where `connection` is any regular ADO.NET connection (`SqlConnection` etc). The use of LINQ's `Single()` will automatically throw an exception if there are zero or multiple matches. Otherwise, `activePatient` will contain the column returned. Note that you could replace `<int>` here with `<Patient>` to have it populate an entire object-model.

Comment: for how long can I use dapper - I want to adopt an ORM but am not sure if they would be around for long. Thanks

Comment: @codingbiz can you rephrase the question? are you concerned about object lifetime? (if so: not an issue - dapper has no identity/change-manager - it is deliberately light-weight) - or are you concerned about product lifetime? in which case... it is fully F/OSS, hosted separately in 3 places (nuget,github,google-code) - it isn't going anywhere!

Comment: It's the product's life time. You mean I can use dapper for years to come? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
string  ds = String.Format("{0}", UserDataBase.ExecuteScalar(Command));
```

Comment: @PollyShaw It's good practice as well to explain *why* a particular bit of code would fix a problem - point out what the original error is, and how your code fixes this.

Comment: actually it is sql exception..want to change stored procedure ..check out previous comments for thsi doubt..